# При использовании нескольких пользовательских функций возникает "user-defined function raised exception"

Tags: python, sqlite

Функцию

```py
def lower_string(_str):
    return _str.lower()
```

Добавляю в базу

```py
con.create_function("LOWER", 1, lower_string)
```

И выполняю запрос

```sql
SELECT * FROM incoming WHERE lower("index") LIKE lower("%иванов%")
```

Функция-то отлично срабатывает но как только добавляю OR

```sql
SELECT * FROM incoming WHERE lower("index") LIKE lower("%иванов%") OR
lower("num_incoming") LIKE lower("%иванов%")
```

то сразу возникает ошибка

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception
```

Собственно почему ошибка возникает только в случае наличия OR возникает ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось достаточно очевидно: т.к. в таблице не все поля имели строковый тип, то функция lower() не могла их обработать. Чтобы исправить ошибку я просто добавил преобразование в строку:

```py
def lower_string(_str):
    return str(_str).lower()
```